# Display a file's icon image in an ImageView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application which permits the user to select a file. The file could be an application.

I want to display the file's icon in an JavaFX `ImageView`.

Is there a cross-platform solution to get such icon image and display it in an `ImageView`?

Comment: Have you looked at [`FileSystemView#getSystemIcon(file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon-java.io.File-)?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha no, I didn't know it was compatible with JavaFX's `ImageView`. How do I apply it? It returns a Swing `Icon` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default system icon for a file by using [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html):

```
ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
java.awt.Image image = icon.getImage();
```

You can later use [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) to convert it to FX Image and set it to an ImageView.

Also go through [JavaFX file listview with icon and file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034432/javafx-file-listview-with-icon-and-file-name).